# Illegal invoke-super to void com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.setResult

Tags: android

Introducing firebase, the following problems occurred:

Illegal invoke-super to void   com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.setResult(com.google.android.gms.common.api.Result) from class com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BaseImplementation$ApiMethodImpl

my project gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting this issue while creating signed `apk` file. If yes then this is because of missing `proguard` rules.

Add rules like below:

```
verbose
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** {com.google.android.gms.internal.** initialize(android.content.Context);}
# -dontnote com.google.android.gms.internal.**
# -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.internal.**
```